# Pass specific row's td values to JavaScript as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this one table which contains some marks:

```
<table>
  <tr class = 'common'>
    <td contenteditable = 'true' name = 'marks'>10</td>
    <td contenteditable = 'true' name = 'marks'>50</td>
    <td contenteditable = 'true' name = 'marks'>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class = 'common'>
    <td contenteditable = 'true' name = 'marks'>40</td>
    <td contenteditable = 'true' name = 'marks'>20</td>
    <td contenteditable = 'true' name = 'marks'>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I wanted to pass all the numbers for a specific row when I made some changes at that row.

For instance, I would like to change the number 50 to 10 which is on the first row. Then, all the numbers on the first row will be passed to JavaScript as an array. Same goes to the second row, if I made some changes on the second row, all the numbers on the second row will be passed to JavaScript as an array.

The number of rows are not fixed. Therefore, it could be more than 2.

```
$(document).on('blur', '.common td[contenteditable]', function() {
      var numArray = array(); // 10,10,40   
});
```

Comment: Didn't understood this part *Then, all the numbers on the first row will be passed to JavaScript*

Comment: @gurvinder372 All the td values on the first row will be passed to JavaScript as an array.

Comment: @MohammadThaqifTaher Rory's answer should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through all the `td` with jQuery's `each()` like the following:

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.common td[contenteditable]', function() {
  var numArray = [];
  var allTD = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').each(function(){
    numArray.push($(this).text());
  });
  console.log(numArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class = 'common'>
    <td contenteditable='true' name='marks'>10</td>
    <td name='marks'>50</td>
    <td name='marks'>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class = 'common'>
    <td contenteditable = 'true' name = 'marks'>40</td>
    <td name = 'marks'>20</td>
    <td name = 'marks'>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can hook an `input` event handler to your `contenteditable` cell. Then you can use `map()` to build an array of the cell values within the modified row, ready to use in your AJAX request. Something like this:

```js
$('.common td[contenteditable]').on('input', function() {
  var marks = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').map(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim();
  }).get();
  console.log(marks);

  // make your AJAX call here...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="common">
    <td contenteditable="true" name="marks">10</td>
    <td name="marks">50</td>
    <td name="marks">40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="common">
    <td contenteditable="true" name="marks">40</td>
    <td name="marks">20</td>
    <td name="marks">10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Agh didn't see your answer.  I'll delete mine.  This is the right one though